# PHP semicolon delimited file generation

Tags: php, excel, delimiter

I am using this code to generate a Semicolon delimited file:

```
for ($i = 0; $i < 3; $i = $i+1)
{   
array_push($dataArray,"$dataCell1","$dataCell2","$dataCell3","$dataCell4","$dataCell5","$dataCell6","$dataCell7","$dataCell8","$dataCell9","$dataCell10","$dataCell11");

$stringData = rtrim(implode(';', $dataArray), ';'); //rtrim will prevent the last cell to be imploded by ';'            

$stringData .= "\r\n";
}
```

**What I want is:**

[image]

(Data separated by semicolon and rows separated by newLine)

**What I get is:**
[image]
(Data is separated by semicolons but new lines are not added, all data appears in a sngle line)

Please tell me what I am doing wrong..

Comment: Use `<br>` and not `\r\n`. Also, you can use `$i++` instead of `$i = $i+1`.

Comment: Use [fputcsv()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fputcsv.php) instead of this broken homebrew; and use the correct headers so the output is treated as csv and not as html markup

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is in your logic. You keep on adding to the data to your $dataArray with every iteration, while the following statement in your code will set stingData to the imploded value of $dataArray **ONLY IN THE LAST LOOP ITERATION**. And at that point, $dataArray contains all the data values because you kept pushing to it for 3 iterations.

```
$stringData = rtrim(...)
```

What you want to do is this:

```
<?php

//concatenation string
$stringData = '';

for ($i = 0; $i < 3; $i = $i+1)
{ 
    //init the array with every iteration. 
    $dataArray = array();

    //push your values
    array_push($dataArray,"$dataCell1","$dataCell2","$dataCell3","$dataCell4","$dataCell5","$dataCell6","$dataCell7","$dataCell8","$dataCell9","$dataCell10","$dataCell11");

    //concatenate
    $stringData  .= rtrim(implode(';', $dataArray), ';'); 

    //new line
    $stringData .= "\r\n";
} 

//print
echo $stringData . "\n";
?>
```

Comment: Darn how could I skip such a quality step here :) Thanks man!

Answer (score 0):

Use `fputcsv` instead:

```
// indexed array of data
$data = [
    ['col1' => 1, 'col2' => 2, 'col3' => 3],
    ['col1' => 6, 'col2' => 7, 'col3' => 9],
    ['col1' => 5, 'col2' => 8, 'col3' => 15],
]

// add headers for each column in the CSV download
array_unshift($data, array_keys(reset($data)));

$handle = fopen('php://output', 'w');
foreach ($data as $row) {
    fputcsv($handle, $row, ';', '"');
}
fclose($handle);
```

Answer (score 0):

For creating a csv file, `fputcsv` is indeed the best method.

First start by saving your data in an "array of arrays". That makes handling the data easier:

```
$dataArray = array();

for ($i = 0; $i < 3; $i = $i+1)
    $dataArray[$i] = array($dataCell1,$dataCell2,$dataCell3,$dataCell4,$dataCell5,$dataCell6,$dataCell7,$dataCell8,$dataCell9,$dataCell10,$dataCell11);
```

Next we need to create a handle to a temporary file, while also making sure we have the rights to do so. We'll then store all the array entries in the temporary file with the correct delimiter.

```
$handle = fopen('php://temp', 'r+');

foreach($dataArray as $line)
    fputcsv($handle, $line, ';', '"');

rewind($handle);
```

If you just want to print the results to a page, the following code will do:

```
$contents = "";

while(!feof($handle))
    $contents .= fread($handle, 8192);

fclose($handle);

echo $contents;
```

Be aware that in plain html, the line breaks are not displayed. If you however check the source code of the resulting page, you can see the line breaks.

But if you also want to save the values in a downloadable csv file, you'll need the following code instead:

```
$fileName = "file.csv";
header('Content-Type: application/csv');
header('Content-Disposition: attachement; filename="' . $fileName . '";');
fpassthru($handle);
fclose($handle);
```